# Assigning DOM style to var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason if I type in:

```
var i = document.getElementById('fake').style.backgroundPosition;
```

I get undefined.

However,

```
document.getElementById('fake').style.backgroundPosition;
```

by itself, returns the right answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming you're typing this into the terminal ("... if I type in...")? Have you tried it in actual code?

Comment: Where are you putting `document.getElementById('fake').style.backgroundPosition;`?  How can it "give you the right answer" if you're not assigning it to anything.  It can't be an actual javascript line of code then.  Also, how can we possibly answer why the second one "gives you the right answer" when you don't tell us where you're putting it?

Comment: Voting to close because the question is unclear and the OP has not responded to questions asking them to clarify.

Comment: When you do `var i = document.getElementById('fake').style.backgroundPosition;` are you trying to get the actual style setting for that object?  Doing it this way only gets the value of inline HTML style attributes - it does not reflect style sheet settings.

Comment: What does document.getElementById('fake') return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I use that line of code on an element that actually exists in Chrome, I get `i` equal to an empty string.  You can see that here in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/b6syd/.

So, if you are getting undefined, then probably your object "fake" doesn't exist when you're running the code.

`element.style.backgroundPosition` will only return to you an actual inline style settings or programmatically values set for that particular object directly.  It won't return computed styles from stylesheets.  If you want to get the current style setting for that attribute, then you need to use something like this:

```
var i = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('fake'), null).getPropertyValue('background-position');
```

And, it's different in IE.  This is where a framework like jQuery or YUI is very useful.

In jQuery, it would just be this:

```
var i = $("#fake").css('backgroundPosition');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - that depends upon whether what the OP is really trying to do is get the computedStyle value for the backgroundPosition (which they did not include in their question).  This wouldn't explain why the above two values were different, but it might explain to them how to have a line of javascript that will assign a correct value to i which is ultimately what they may need.

Comment: Your answer has a very good explaination about `computedStyle` no doubt but OP is looking for the reason why is he getting it `undefined` when he set it into a variable but not when he uses it directly.

Comment: Perhaps if the OP included one shred of helpful info in that direction one could offer some answers in that direction.  This is an incomplete question with two comment/questions beneath that have not been responded to as such all we can do is guess what the OP really needs.

Comment: I posted the most helpful information I could based on my guess for what the OP actually needs help with.  It may or may not be what the OP actually needs (you have a different guess that is more literal, but might not actually be their problem), but it is impossible to know without more info than the OP has provided.  Anyway, we ought not argue with each other, but rather with the OP about what question they really want help with.

Comment: It needed a few things it turns out. Mainly, background position returns empty unless it is explicitly set inline. The CSS file doesn't do it either, strangely enough. Setting style="" explicitly to 0px 0px solved the problem.